# Ошибки компиляции MyDataAdapter

Tags: c#

Может, что в using добавить надо?

Ошибки при комияции:

Error   1   The name 'MyDataAdapter' does not exist in the current context  e:\all\a\b\Form1.cs

Error   2   The name 'MyConnectionString' does not exist in the current context e:\all\a\b\Form1.cs

Код:

```
  BindingSource MyBindingSorce = new BindingSource();
  MyDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable", MyConnectionString);
  DataTable MyDataTable = new DataTable();
  MyDataAdapter.Fill(MyDataTable);
  MyBindingSorce.DataSource = MyDataTable;
```

Код:

```
SqlCommandBuilder MyCommandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(MyDataAdapter);
            MyDataAdapter.UpdateCommand = MyCommandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(true);
```

Comment: Угу. Надо добавить в using. И не только в него)

Comment: @test123 так а что добавить то? и не только в него ... что именно конкретно.

Comment: У меня смутные сомнения по поводу вашего кода. По мне - вы скопировали его с какой то статьи и в упор не видите что это шаблон кода, а не код... Так что, мой ответ - вам нужно добавить код. Которого тут нет)

Comment: @test123 смотрите шапку. добавил. да из статьи. там только этот код и все

Comment: Ничего не изменилось. Я не могу ответить на ваш вопрос, потому что: 1. У вас нет вопроса на который можно однозначно ответить. 2. Вы не хотите говорить что вам надо. 3. Вы не показали что вы сделали, и как вы пытались решить проблему (хотя, какая проблема, вы же не сказали в чём вопрос). ИМХО - сейчас вы не знаете что вам надо, вопрос требует правки.

Answer (score 2):

Вам же пишут, что MyDataAdapter и MyConnectionString не существуют.
У вас значения в этих переменных есть?
Есть где в коде раньше

```
string MyConnectionString = "Data Source=VASHA_DATASOURCE_ONAJE_VASHA_BAZA.db"?;
```

И видна ли она из этой области? По этому куску кода я вижу, что надо объявить.

Comment: Да нету у него нифига, он код с cyberforum-а 3 летней давности сюда перекидывает, и просит что то сделать, чтобы он работал